# Parsing log to recover SQL insert info

Tags: sql, parsing, sed, awk

I've managed to miss a single letter and deleted about 10000+ SQL records.... in two different tables.
Anyway, I've been reading and testing software in the last 4 hours to recover those records. In short, forget about it...
However, I do have the application logs enabled at full verbose.
This is an example:

```
07.03 17:04:30|      |         » 0
07.03 17:04:30|      |SQLSERVER» MyProcedure.InsertHeader:insert into mytable(myFields,...) values(0,etc)
07.03 17:04:30|      |         #1
```

My simple question is how can I parse this without user intervention?
So that the final result is only:

```
insert into mytable(myFields,...) values(0,etc)
```

I have 1 month of this kind of logs to recover, and besides Insert info, there's too many other lines with diferent info.
I don't care if it is in Linux or Windows, something like awk, sed, anything, would be great and a really good help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from your current example, this line works:

```
grep -io "insert into .*" file
```

From your input(example), the sql, which you want to extract, starts with "insert into". and it is unique. So it is pretty easy to find and extract. If it doesn't work with your real data, please paste some more example as input.

Comment: Ah.... sometimes the simple answer is really the best! I was already working on a little utility. Thanks